Encoding real values with homomorphic encryption
I have been searching for the material on homomorphic division. I came across the following article,
How can we define division operation by using Fully homomorphic encryption
There is a reference for the paper at the above link. However, the link does not lead to the paper. Could the author of the answer help me with the link?
Thanks very much.
Bhavin.

So your question is actually about encoding floating-point numbers so that they can be encrypted and manipulated homomorphically?

Indeed, I want to do exactly that.

There are several ways to encode floating-point values so that encrypting them allow you to operate homomorphically.
First of all, it is worth noticing that nowadays the simplest (?) way of homomorphically operating with floating-point values is by using the CKKS scheme.
But if you want to use other schemes, such as BGV, then you basically have to find a way of representing floating points values with polynomials so that adding and multiplying those polynomials corresponds to adding and multiplying the original values, that is, you need an encoding $\mu$ that takes a real number $r$ and outputs a polynomial $p_r(X)$ such that

$\mu(r_0) + \mu(r_1) = \mu(r_0 + r_1)$
$\mu(r_0) \cdot \mu(r_1) = \mu(r_0 \cdot r_1)$

Then, thanks to the homomorphic properties, you can encode then encrypt, and the homomorphic operations will work as expected over the original real numbers. For instance,
$$ \mathtt{Hom.Add}\left( \mathtt{Enc}(\mu(r_0)) , \mathtt{Enc}(\mu(r_1)) \right) = \mathtt{Enc}(\mu(r_0) + \mu(r_1)) = \mathtt{Enc}(\mu(r_0  + r_1))$$
So if you decrypt then decode, you obtain $r_0 + r_1$, as expected.
There are many ways of implementing this encoding function. The basic idea is to represent $r$ in some basis $B$ (e.g., $B = 2$) such that
$$ r = r_{-d}\cdot B^{-d} + r_{-d+1}\cdot B^{-d+1} + ... + r_0 + r_1 \cdot B + ... + r_n \cdot B^{n}$$
where the digits $r_{-1}, ..., r_{-d}$ represent the decimal part of $r$ and
$r_0, ..., r_n$ represent the integral part.
For instance, $B=2$ and $r = 4.5$, then $n = 2$, $d=1$,
$r_0 = 0$, $r_1 = 0$, $r_2 = 1$, and $r_{-1} = 1$.
Then, this basic encoding function shifts $r$ multiplying it by $B^d$ so that it becomes the integer
$$ B^d \cdot r = r_{-d}+ r_{-d+1}\cdot B^{1} + ... + r_0 \cdot B^d+ r_1 \cdot B^{d+1} + ... + r_n \cdot B^{d+n}$$
and sends $B^d \cdot r$ to the polynomial
$p(X) = \sum_{i=0}^{n+d} r_{i-d} \cdot X^{i}$.
To decode, you evaluate $p$ on $B$ and divide by $B^d$, since
$p(B) / B^d = (B^d \cdot r) / B^d = r$.
You can check that the encoding respects the additive and multiplicative properties, at least while the degree of the encoded polynomial is not larger then $N$, when working modulo $X^N+1$, and while the coefficients are less $t$, when working with plaintext modulus $t$ (well, there are some technicalities, because you have to keep track of the scaling factor you applied and adjust it before homomorphic additions, if needed).
There are more involved techniques where you can use windows (sequences of zeros between the non-zero coefficients) [CSVW16] or even use the basis $B$ as a real number itself [BBBCIV17].

Thanks very much for the detailed answer. However, I could not could not figure out how division could be performed from the description. May be I will make my question clear.


Suppose $A,B\in \mathbb R$. Encrypt $A,B$, using CKKS, and want to perform $Encryption(A)/Encryption(B)$.


Does $\mu(r_0)=p_{r_0}(X)$ in the description above?



The question you linked is only about division by a known message, that is, a plaintext. Division by a ciphertext is totally different (and not covered by the question you linked or by this answer). For this, you have to use some algorithm to compute inverses, i.e., $1/x$. This is not simple, but you can search on some papers about CKKS. I remember some of them analyze this.

So you mean, I compute $1/B$, as a plaintext and multiply it with the ciphertext $Enc(A)$ to get the $Enc(A/B)$?

If $B$ is a known value (as in the computation of the average), then yes, you can do it. But there are of course ways of computing enc(1/B) from enc(B) (i.e., homomorphically computing the inverse), it is just that this is much more costly then simply encoding 1/B then encrypting it.

I came across the the article - on page 7. However, it does only work for numbers in $(0,2)$. To make sure that the number belongs to the interval I must carry out comparison - which is very costly again.

Depending on the application (for instance, neural networks), you can have loose bounds for the encrypted values during the computation, them divide by this bound to bring it to the $]0,2[$ interval. For instance, if you encrypt image pixels, you know fresh values lie in [0, 2^8]. Then, if you multiply them, the values are in [0, 2^16]. Then, dividing by the plaintext 2^15 brings the values to [0, 2].
